# Laravel query limit by sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have model `User`, which hasMany model `Video`.
Model `Video` has column `length`.
Let's say, each video has `length` from few sec to 8000 sec for example.

I want to query specific `User` with his `Videos`, result has to be limited by sum of totall video length.

What I am looking for is to return all users with a collection of videos for each user.
However, this video collection for each user must contain a random selection of their videos so that the total length of their video collection is, for example, between 10,000 and 12,000 seconds.
So there will be either a lot of short videos or 2 long ones etc.
The query must return users with a collection of videos, when this entire collection of randomly selected videos is of the required length.
Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$users = User::whereHas('videos', function($q) {
   $q->select(\DB::raw('SUM(length) as sum_length'))
       ->havingRaw('sum_length < 10000');
   });
});
```

Comment: Hey Hossein, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. 
What I am looking for is to return all users  with a collection of videos for each user. 
However, this video collection for each user must contain a random selection of their videos so that the total length of their video collection is, for example, between 10,000 and 12,000 seconds. So there will be either a lot of short videos or 2 long ones etc. the query must return users with a collection of videos, when this entire collection of randomly selected videos is of the required length.